# Daily Eight Hours of Audio Recording from my spare computer

Tags: audio, audio-recording, voice-recording

I would like to use my spare computer as an Audio recording system, which records **8 hours of recording daily**. It would be like an audio surveillance system. The audio quality does not have to be HD, as long as I can hear it fairly well. It is not meant for spying or any illegal stuff, just recording the surrounding sounds of birds, wind, sort of white noise.

**Nice to have features** feature would be

- An automatic upload to google drive or something similar. Preferably deleting the local file after the upload.
- Scheduling of time to start and stop.
- Audio quality can be just low to medium, which does not take up lots of space.

My spare computer is fairly configured and has SSD. So, I think it should be able to handle 8 hours of audio recording!

The software I looked at so far,

- Audio Recorders (has audio length limit)
- Audacity (Not sure how to automate it?)

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You do not mention your operating system. So you can use for example [fmedia](https://sourceforge.net/projects/fmedia/). It runs on Windows, Linux (possibly MacOS too). AFAIK it do not have limitations for recording. It work via GUI or command line. You can set the limit (in seconds) of recording as well as output format and quality.

For automation, you can use `scheduler` or `cron` and the command line way of running.

Comment: Thanks. I am using Windows 10. I will check out fmedia. thanks.